# Dynamo get items from last X days using composite key

Tags: dynamodb

I have the following sort key in a dynamo db table:

```
YYYY-MM-DD#<USER_ID>#<CATEGORY_ID>
```

Im trying to solve the following two access patterns:

1. get all item for a user in the last x days
2. get all items for a user and category in the last x days

I can satisfy the 2nd access pattern with the following conditional expression:

```
sort_key BETWEEN 2018-01-02#<USER_ID>#<CATEGORY_ID> and 2019-01-02#<USER_ID>#<CATEGORY_ID>
```

This returns several items between 2018-01-02 and 2019-01-02

However, if I try to satisfy the 1st access pattern I cant get it to work. I've tried:

```
sort_key BETWEEN 2018-01-02#<USER_ID> and 2019-01-02#<USER_ID>
```

But only one item is returned, the item with date 2018-01-02, but I should be getting multiple items returned.

I searched online for any wildcard operators with conditional expression, but couldn't find any. Any ideas how I can satisfy access pattern 1?